# Problems rotating view

Tags: ios, swift

I want to animate a UIImageView. The image should only spin clockwise. When the image is spinning, I want to speed it up. When I do speed it up, it goes counterclockwise and the start position is not correct as well. This is my code:

```
func rotateAnimation(theView: UIView, duration: CFTimeInterval = 2.0, repeatCount: Float = 1, toValue: CGFloat = CGFloat(.pi * 2.0), linear: Bool = false, animation: String = "transform.rotation") {
    let rotateAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: animation)
    let currentLayer = (theView.layer.presentation())
    var currentAngle = CFloat((currentLayer?.value(forKeyPath: "transform.rotation") as? NSNumber)!)
    currentAngle = roundf(currentAngle * 180 / Float(Double.pi))
    print(currentAngle)
    rotateAnimation.fromValue = currentAngle
    if !linear{
    rotateAnimation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn)
    }
    rotateAnimation.toValue = toValue
    rotateAnimation.duration = duration
    rotateAnimation.repeatCount = repeatCount
    theView.layer.add(rotateAnimation, forKey: nil)
}
```

The print shows me to correct angle.

I am calling this method below twice. The second time I am calling it, the image is spinning counterclock:

```
    rotateAnimation(theView: star, duration: 15.0, repeatCount: Float.infinity, toValue: CGFloat(Double.pi * 2), linear: true)
    delay(delay: 3.5, closure: {
      self.rotateAnimation(theView: self.star, duration: 7, repeatCount: Float.infinity, toValue: CGFloat(Double.pi * 2), linear: true)
    })
```

Comment: You need do this with `CAKeyFramedAnimation`